# Calling Rest webservice using JQuery Ajax call , web service is returning JSON string

Tags: jquery, json, web-services

I have made a Rest Web Service:

```
package org.jboss.samples.rs.webservices;


import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;



@Path("/MyRESTApplication")
public class HelloWorldResource {


    @GET()
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/dealInfo/{dealId}")
    public String sayHello(@PathParam("dealId") int dealId) {
        System.out.println("dealid......"+dealId);
        switch(dealId) {
        case 1 :System.out.println("employee id.....");
            return "{'name':'George Koch', 'age':58}";
        case 2:
            return "{'name':'Peter Norton', 'age':50}";
        default:
            return "{'name':'unknown', 'age':-1}";
    } // end of switch

    }
}
```

When I go to internet explorer & type this in the address bar:

```
http://localhost:8080/nagarro-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/MyRESTApplication/dealInfo/2
```

It is giving me:

```
{'name':'Peter Norton', 'age':50}
```

But when I call it using an ajax call in a JQuery method. e.g.

```
$.ajax({  
           type: "GET",  
           url: "http://localhost:8080/nagarro-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/MyRESTApplication/dealInfo/2",  
           data: "",  
           success: function(resp){  
             // we have the response  
             alert("Server said123:\n '" + resp + "'");  
           },  
           error: function(e){  
             alert('Error121212: ' + e);  
           }  
         });
```

I am getting an Error in this call.

[image]

When I am debugging using F12 in IE, I am getting following as well

```
"Invalid JSON: {\'name\':\'Peter Norton\', \'age\':50}"
```

**Would anybody tell me what could be the problem in my call.**

Comment: How do I call this web service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are not returning a valid json: try something like:

```
  return  "{\"name\":\"unknown\", \"age\":-1}"
```

because this

```
{
    "name": "unknown",
    "age": -1
}
```

is a valid JSON (You must use `"`, not `'`) while this is not

```
{
    'name': 'unknown',
    'age': -1
}
```

You should also specify the datatype

```
 $.ajax({  
       type: "GET",  
       url: "http://localhost:8080/nagarro-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/MyRESTApplication/dealInfo/2",  
       dataType: "json",  
       success: function(resp){  
         // we have the response  
         alert("Server said123:\n '" + resp.name + "'");  
       },  
       error: function(e){  
         alert('Error121212: ' + e);  
       }  
     });
```

Comment: it is working fine, but I just want to know that whenever we specify @Produces(application/json) then why there is a need to give datatype as JSON on client side.

Comment: @SAM there is no need, jQuery will guess it right i think (i'm no java expert though)

Answer (score 4):

Your service and output is right.

Problem is same orgin policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Ajax does not allow access to inner level service.
For example, in the www.example.com/index.html, you can not access 
www.example.com/service/book?id=1.
Because you changed your context path from www.example.com to www.example.com/service/book.
This is not allowed for security but we have one solution

Previously, I had same problem and I solved it with below code. 
I think it can help you.
Key point is `dataType: 'json'`

```
    function testService()
                {
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        dataType: 'json',
                        headers: {
                            Accept:"application/json",
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                        },
                        type:'GET',
                        url:'http://localhost:8080/service/book/search/1',
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            document.writeln("Book id : " + data.id);
                            document.writeln("Book title : " + data.name);
                            document.writeln("Description : " + data.description);
                        },
                        error: function(data)
                        {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your output.
your quotes are not valid.

```
{"name":"toto"} is ok

{'name':'toto'} is not
```