# Calling Restful Web service using jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, rest

I've made a RESTful web service at localhost in Java. When I type the following url in my navigator address bar :

```
http://localhost:8080/GeonotesApp2-war/webresources/route/1
```

It will give me :

```
{"rid":"1","routeComment":"hhhahahahah","routeDateCreate":"2012-04-03T00:00:00+02:00","routeDistance":"13400.0","routeName":"route1","routeUserId":"1"}
```

Now I want to use an Ajax call to get this JSON information with this script :

```
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/GeonotesApp2-war/webresources/route/1",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            },
            success: function(resp) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(e) {
                alert("error: "+e);
            }
        });
    });

</script>   
</head>
<body>
    Hello Test Service!
</body>
```

However I'm always getting the error message :

```
error: [object Object]
```

I found this post and followed exactly what it does, but doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks

[Calling Rest webservice using JQuery Ajax call , web service is returning JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481073/calling-rest-webservice-using-jquery-ajax-call-web-service-is-returning-json-s)

Comment: Change your error handler to `function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )`, then you can see what the actual error is. The `[object Ojbect]` you're getting back is the jqXHR object.

Comment: @G_M I've tried change error handler to function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown), I alert textStatus, it displays : error : error, when I alert errorThrown, there is nothing after 'error:'

Comment: What about `jqXHR.responseText`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The headers have to be on the service side. So the browser knows that the server allows this website to use Ajax to load the data. So these headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
```

Links:

- [Set server headers](http://enable-cors.org/server.html)
- [Client support](http://enable-cors.org/client.html)

Comment: Only if you load from a different domain. Otherwise you will get a `security error`