# Calling REST web service from java script

Tags: jquery, rest

We are calling a REST web service from a jquery. 
The target url happens to be on different domain.

We have already referred below url to get this working.

[Calling Restful Web service using jQuery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152507/calling-restful-web-service-using-jquery-ajax)

But the real issue is , the target REST web service is not returning the response headers required for CROSS CONTEXT working.
(as mentioned in the above url) , and REST web service is not in our control . Hence we are getting failure response from 
REST web service.

Is there any way we can resove this issue and get this cross context thing working ?

Also , we tested the same REST service through REST plugin in Mozilla (add on) , found out that server returns success

Also rest web service uses "Basic authentication" mechanism for web security .

Comment: The easiest way it to consume the web service from a server script and then populate it as you please.

Comment: @alkis: yes , that is the simple option , but can we do some work around in java script and achieve this ?

Comment: Since the response doesn't have the headers needed, hence doesn't allow cors, you don't have a choice. The part with the addon is troublesome. Did you try to view the source code of that addon?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using AJAX using **jsonp** in JQuery, yet this may workout only for all GET API calls.

The better approach would be handling REST API url using **curl** in any PHP file.

This really works for **cross-domain** urls...